# Difficulties in integrating "tui-editor-1.0.3"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tui

I am facing difficulties in integrating "[tui-editor-1.0.3](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.editor)" in a webpage.

It throws an error : `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined"` 
The source of error was at line number `19122` of `tui-Editor-editor.js`, where exist  `null` value in `this._currentButton` and it tries to access `this._currentButton.scrollIntoView()`.

I tried to check for `null` values before accessing `this._currentButton.scrollIntoView`, but it does not produce appropriate view of editor.

How to make sure that `this._currentButton` is always not null-able? Or, any other solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced same issue today.

I'm very new to try TUI Editor, so am not sure what the right solution is. But according to read the code, specifying `codeBlockLanguages` option might avoid this error.

```
var editor = new tui.Editor({
    el: document.querySelector('#editor'),
    initialEditType: 'markdown',
    previewStyle: 'vertical',
    height: '300px',
    codeBlockLanguages: ['ruby', 'PHP', 'javascript'],
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually helped and should be marked as the correct answer!